strange phenomenon that %JAVA_HOME% is not dir-able
I have set %JAVA_HOME% as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23.
When I echo %JAVA_HOME%, it will return C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23. When I cd %JAVA_HOME%, it will take me to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23.
However, when I dir %JAVA_HOME%, it will complain that:

The system cannot find the path specified.


This is so strange. what's wrong?

Incidentally, I have set my JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23, but where java returns C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe. Does it matter?

Have you tried dir %JAVA_HOME% /a?

it will still return The system cannot find the path specified.

How about dir "%JAVA_HOME%"

Please don't upload images of code. Click on Edit and copy-paste the commands and output.

yes, that will work. why? @Mippy

Shells use spaces to separate arguments. If an argument itself contains spaces, you need to quote it. The program doesn't see the variable, the shell does the replacement before invoking the command.

@HoyCheung It's probably because of a space somewhere in the path, likely the Program Files folder

how came cd works?

I genuinely don't know whycd works, but it is possibly more lenient.

@HoyCheung Upon further research, it could be due to cd not having any arguments after the drive path, while dir does

fair~
Thanks @Mippy

I should also mention, because of your statement about the result of where java, that you may wish to consider also updating your Path environment variable content to point to the newer version too. You could therefore add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the value list for that variable name. The choice of where you add that is important, the higher up that list you put it, decides which java.exe is used. So if you'd like it to be the default version used, when relying on just the filename in your command-line, ensure that it is placed before the %CommonProgramFiles%\Oracle\Java\javapath entry.

The issue is that the %JAVA_HOME% path contains spaces, which are delimiters, so it won't find the correct file
The solution is to change your command to:
dir "%JAVA_HOME%"

cdworks because, as per the documentation,

Spaces aren't treated as delimiters, so  can contain spaces without enclosing quotation marks. For example:
cd username\programs\start menu

